# Why i still get charged amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

Hello guys i have a weird problem with my amazon account..I enable the S3 free tier service and i upload some files to the bucket.After 1 month i remove all the files and i delete the bucket..I thought that i have finish with this but then yestarday i recieved a weird email that says amazon will charge me if i dont disable my Free Tier Services.In my account setting i can see [image]

but its weird because i dont have any buckets

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the `2 Requests`? Don't panic. You get the first 20,000 GET requests free each month during your first 12 months. And they are only charged at `$0.0055 per 1000 requests`. If you look at your Billing Console, you should see that you weren't charged for them.

Answer (score 1):

As you've now deleted the S3 bucket you should not be charged anything, it's possible that the notification was delayed. If you have multiple accounts ensure that you're in the correct account.

The 2 requests in your screenshot are presumably from two `ListBuckets` requests when you attempted to view your S3 buckets in your AWS account.

Just in case you're using organisations with shared billing be aware that the free tier would be used by a single account.

At the end of the month you should receive your billing for the month, if S3 is added there you can use [Cost Explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/) to dive into your service usage that might help to identify any resource(s) you were not aware of. Using this would cost `$0.01` per query to the service.